# Linker Error XCode 5 - Phonegap Estimote Plugin

Tags: cordova, xcode5, ibeacon

I am using Phonegap 3 and I successfully setup my project.

I added this plugin - https://github.com/kdzwinel/phonegap-estimotebeacons from the phonegap command line.

This plugin required me to add the Estimote SDK found here - https://github.com/Estimote/iOS-SDK

I followed instructions and I added my project build phases

I also added an entry in the header search paths.

When I build my project, I get the following error

> Ld
>   /Users/manhattanassociates/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-bujsvxnxcvwnudceybglzoiagwbz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloWorld.app/HelloWorld
>   normal i386
>       cd /Users/WMOS/phonegap/hello/platforms/ios
>       setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 5.0
>       setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode 3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode
>   3.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode\ 3.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode\ 3.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator7.0.sdk
>   -L/Users/manhattanassociates/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-bujsvxnxcvwnudceybglzoiagwbz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -L/Users/WMOS/phonegap/hello/platforms/ios/EstimoteSDK/Headers -F/Users/manhattanassociates/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-bujsvxnxcvwnudceybglzoiagwbz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -filelist /Users/manhattanassociates/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-bujsvxnxcvwnudceybglzoiagwbz/Build/Intermediates/HelloWorld.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloWorld.build/Objects-normal/i386/HelloWorld.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -weak_framework CoreFoundation -weak_framework UIKit -weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak-lSystem -force_load
>   /Users/manhattanassociates/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-bujsvxnxcvwnudceybglzoiagwbz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a
>   -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0 -framework SystemConfiguration -framework CoreBluetooth -lEstimoteSDK7 -framework AssetsLibrary /Users/manhattanassociates/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-bujsvxnxcvwnudceybglzoiagwbz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libCordova.a
>   -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreLocation -weak_framework ImageIO -Xlinker -dependency_info
>   -Xlinker /Users/manhattanassociates/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-bujsvxnxcvwnudceybglzoiagwbz/Build/Intermediates/HelloWorld.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloWorld.build/Objects-normal/i386/HelloWorld_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/manhattanassociates/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloWorld-bujsvxnxcvwnudceybglzoiagwbz/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloWorld.app/HelloWorld
>
> ld: library not found for -lEstimoteSDK7 clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Any idea as to what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure that you have included the library correctly? If so, make sure that you have also included `ESTBeaconManager.h` as shown here: http://imgur.com/6QGh5oB .